# how can i automatically send payments through paypal using php

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I have a database having money information, I need to send to co-workers and that amount automatically goes when the workers click "request money" button. Can this be done? Will paypal allow me to do that?

I tried to make use of paypal adaptive payment,but it requires that invoke paypal login and authorize here then send money.

I need this process automatically.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: I sure hope this is not possible.

Comment: Sorry, but that is the silliest thing I've seen today. Why would you even allow people to essentially **"TAKE"** money from you all willy-nilly?

Comment: You may use Paypal Pro api for this requirement but you have to fill some information from your site.Read the document of Paypal Pro.

Comment: Situation like that:When subscribers visit to my site and view ads we have to reward them per ads as 0.05 cents.When this amount reach $5.They need to withdraw this amount.So my system need to,subscriber request to withdraw and enter their paypal email id,and system needs to debit respected amount to subscriber paypal account.

Answer (score 1):

Use Paypal mass payments.

Build a list with the pending payments (TSV format) using PHP and submit through Paypal site or using API,

More info:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_batch-payment-overview-outside#tab1
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayOverview/